# How do I evaluate the limit of f(x,a) - a.Ln[ g(x,a) ] when a goes to infinity?

Tags: limits

In the course of analyzing solutions to the one dimensional inverse square law problem I found the implied equality:$$\sqrt{\alpha}(\sqrt{x(x+\alpha)} -\frac{\alpha}{2}Ln[\frac{2x+\alpha +2\sqrt{x(x+\alpha)}}{\alpha}]) =\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{3}{2} .$$ for $0<x$ and Lim $\alpha=$infinity. Numerical evaluation on Excel suggests this is true but this runs into a problem of precision as $\alpha$ gets large ($\alpha>10^6$) because we then have the small difference of very large numbers,so a tiny % error on the numbers leads to a huge % error on the difference. I cannot see how to provide an analytical proof of the equality. Any ideas?

Comment: Expand the logarithm up to order $1/(\alpha\sqrt{\alpha})$ and watch the simplifications occur. Note that $\log(1+u)=u-u^2/2+u^3/3+o(u^3)$ when $u\to0$, to use with $u=2(x+\sqrt{x(x+\alpha)})/\alpha$ of order $1/\sqrt{\alpha}$.

Comment: That was quick! Thanks I will try this approach.

Comment: wow it does simplify it! I understand the approach and the expansion now- I must be getting a bit rusty not to have seen it! I don't think I knew the log expansion. Nice one! Thanks again.